# verificar codigo de compra api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, api

encontre un script de empleo y quiero que el registro del codigo de compra sea opcional para publicarlo en mi web la ruta esta dividida por pasos pero exactamente el step3.blade.php me pide verificar el codigo de compra cosa que no quiero que pase (el codigo no es mio, lo modificare a mi necesidad), espero puedan ayudarme

STEP3.BLADE.PHP:

```
@extends('layouts.app_install')

@section('title_text')
Installing - Step 3
@endsection

@section('title')
Installing - Step 3
@endsection

@section('content')
    <style>
        .btn-info
        {
            background: #4c83c7 !important;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 10px;
            min-width: 140px;
        }
        label
        {
            margin:         0;
            padding:        0;
            color:          #48545f;
            font-family:    'FiraSans', sans-serif;
            font-size:      13.0px;
            font-style:     normal;
            font-stretch:   normal;
            font-weight:    500;
            text-align:     left;
        }
        .form-control
        {
            width:          100%;
            border:         1px solid #b7c5ce;
            color:          #48545f;
            font-family:    'FiraSans', sans-serif;
            font-size:      13.0px;
            font-style:     normal;
            font-stretch:   normal;
            font-weight:    500;
            font-size:      20px;
            border:         1px solid #B7C5CE;
            height:         40px !important;
            margin-top:     10px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="con">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                @if (\Session::has('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ $errors->first('error_msg') == '' ? __('settings.form_error') : $errors->first('error_msg') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ __('settings.saved_successfull') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'install/step3/save')) }}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Purchase key</label>
                                {{ Form::text('product_key', '' , ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Install</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

INSTALLATIONCONTROLLER.PHP:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Fb_account;
    use App\Fb_account_node;
    use App\Fb_app;
use App\Lib\Curl;
use App\Lib\FBLib;
use App\Option;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;


class InstallationController extends Controller
{

    private function checkStep($step)
    {
        if( env('APP_VER' , '') !== '' )
        {
            redirect('update' )->send();
            exit();
        }

        if( $step > 0 && $this->checkRequierments() == false )
        {
            redirect('install' )->send();
            exit();
        }

        $sessStep = session('step' , '1');

        if( $sessStep != $step )
        {
            redirect('install/step' . $sessStep)->send();
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function start()
    {
        if( env('APP_VER' , '') !== '' )
        {
            redirect('update' )->send();
            exit();
        }

        return view('install.start' , ['requirments' => $this->checkRequierments(true) , 'start' => $this->checkRequierments()]);
    }

    private function checkRequierments($returnArray = false)
    {
        $requirments = [
            'allow_url_fopen'       =>  ini_get('allow_url_fopen')                              ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'php_ver'               =>  version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.1.3') >= 0      ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'open_ssl'              =>  extension_loaded('openssl')                             ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'pdo'                   =>  class_exists('PDO')                                     ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'mbstring'              =>  extension_loaded('mbstring')                                ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'json'                  =>  function_exists('json_encode')                  ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'curl'                  =>  function_exists('curl_init')                        ? 'yes' : 'no'
        ];

        if( $returnArray )
        {
            return $requirments;
        }

        foreach( $requirments AS $requirment )
        {
            if( $requirment == 'no' )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function step1()
    {
        $this->checkStep(1);

        return view('install.step1');
    }

    public function step1Save(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'sql_hostname'  =>  'required|string|max:255',
            'sql_username'  =>  'required|string|max:255',
            'sql_database'  =>  'required|string|max:255',
            'sql_password'  =>  'nullable|string|max:255',
        ]);

        config()->set('database.connections.test', [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => $validatedData['sql_hostname'],
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => $validatedData['sql_database'],
            'username' => $validatedData['sql_username'],
            'password' => $validatedData['sql_password'],
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ]);

        try
        {
            DB::connection('test')->select('SELECT 1 test');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error_msg' => 'Connection error!'])->withInput();
        }

        session([
            'step'          =>  2,
            'sql_hostname'  =>  $validatedData['sql_hostname'],
            'sql_username'  =>  $validatedData['sql_username'],
            'sql_database'  =>  $validatedData['sql_database'],
            'sql_password'  =>  $validatedData['sql_password'] ?? ''
        ]);

        return redirect('install/step2');
    }

    public function step2()
    {
        $this->checkStep(2);

        return view('install.step2');
    }

    public function step2Save(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'site_title'        =>  'required|string|max:255',
            'admin_username'    =>  'required|string|max:255',
            'admin_email'       =>  'required|string|email|max:255',
            'admin_password'    =>  'required|string|max:255|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

        session([
            'step'              =>  3,
            'site_title'        =>  $validatedData['site_title'],
            'admin_username'    =>  $validatedData['admin_username'],
            'admin_email'       =>  $validatedData['admin_email'],
            'admin_password'    =>  $validatedData['admin_password']
        ]);

        return redirect('install/step3');
    }

    public function step3()
    {
        $this->checkStep(3);

        return view('install.step3');
    }

    public function step3Save(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'product_key'   =>  'required|string|min:5|max:255'
        ]);

        $productKey = $validatedData['product_key'];

        $checkPurchaseCodeURL = "http://api.emplenio.com/api.php?purchase_code=" . $productKey . "&version=" . config('app.version');
        $result = Curl::getURL($checkPurchaseCodeURL);

        $result = json_decode($result , true);
        $result = is_array( $result ) ? $result : ['status' => 'error' , 'error_msg' => 'Error!!!'];

        if( !($result['status'] == 'ok' && isset($result['sql']) && isset($result['routes'])) )
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error_msg' => isset($result['error_msg']) ? $result['error_msg'] : 'Error!'])->withInput();
        }

        $requiredSessions = ['site_title','admin_username','admin_email','admin_password','sql_hostname','sql_username','sql_database','sql_password'];
        foreach($requiredSessions AS $rSess)
        {
            if( session($rSess , null) === null )
            {
                session()->flush();
                return redirect('install/step1');
            }
        }

        config()->set('database.connections.test', [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => session('sql_hostname'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => session('sql_database'),
            'username' => session('sql_username'),
            'password' => session('sql_password'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ]);

        try
        {
            DB::connection('test')->select('SELECT 1 test');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return redirect('install/step1');
        }

        $pdo = $pdo = DB::connection('test')->getPdo();

        $siteUrl = URL::to('/');

        $envData = "APP_NAME=\"Fb Poster\"\n" .
        "APP_ENV=local\n" .
        "APP_KEY=base64:ZJEEMphpVNqCP7tXfnvU9vOe/EWCghoG482bOgWesck=\n" .
        "APP_DEBUG=false\n" .
        "APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug\n" .
        "APP_VER=".config('app.version')."\n" .
        "APP_URL=\"" . $siteUrl . "\"\n\n" .
        "DB_CONNECTION=\"mysql\"\n" .
        "DB_HOST=\"" . session('sql_hostname') . "\"\n" .
        "DB_PORT=3306\n" .
        "DB_DATABASE=\"" . session('sql_database') . "\"\n" .
        "DB_USERNAME=\"" . session('sql_username') . "\"\n" .
        "DB_PASSWORD=\"" . session('sql_password') . "\"";

        $dbb = base64_decode( $result['sql'] );
        $dbbArray = explode(';' , $dbb);

        foreach( $dbbArray AS $queryOne )
        {
            $queryOne = trim($queryOne);

            if( empty($queryOne) )
                continue;

            $qry = $pdo->prepare( $queryOne );
            $qry->execute();
        }

        DB::connection('test')->table('users')->insert([
            'email'                                 =>  session('admin_email'),
            'username'                              =>  session('admin_username'),
            'password'                              =>  Hash::make(session('admin_password')),
            'timezone'                              =>  'Asia/Baku',
            'language_id'                           =>  '1',
            'records_per_page'                      =>  '25',
            'load_my_groups'                        =>  '1',
            'load_my_pages'                         =>  '1',
            'load_my_ownpages'                      =>  '1',
            'max_groups_to_import'                  =>  '200',
            'max_pages_to_import'                   =>  '200',
            'show_open_groups_only'                 =>  '0',
            'unique_post'                           =>  '0',
            'unique_link'                           =>  '0',
            'post_interval'                         =>  '60',
            'fb_account_id'                         =>  '0',
            'is_admin'                              =>  '1',
            'user_role_id'                          =>  '1',
            'status'                                =>  '1',
            'link_customization'                    =>  '1',
            'created_at'                            =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);

        DB::connection('test')->table('options')->update([
            'site_name' =>  session('site_title')
        ]);

        file_put_contents( base_path('.env') , $envData );
        file_put_contents(base_path('routes/web.php') , base64_decode( $result['routes'] ));

        if( crontab_installed() )
        {
            try
            {
                $cron_file = "/tmp/crontab.txt";
                $cronUrl = url('/');

                $cmd  = "0 0,6,12,18 * * * wget -O /dev/null ".$cronUrl."/schedule/insert_schedules >/dev/null 2>&1\n";
                $cmd .= "*/2 * * * * wget -O /dev/null ".$cronUrl."/schedule/send_posts >/dev/null 2>&1\n";
                $cmd .= "*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null ".$cronUrl."/schedule/auto_resume_post >/dev/null 2>&1";

                $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
                file_put_contents($cron_file, $output . $cmd . PHP_EOL);
                exec("crontab $cron_file");
            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {

            }
        }

        session()->flush();

        return redirect('/');
    }


    public function update()
    {
        if( env('APP_VER' , '') === '' )
        {
            redirect('install' )->send();
            exit();
        }

        return view('install.update');
    }

    public function updateSave(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'product_key'   =>  'required|string|min:5|max:255'
        ]);

        $productKey = $validatedData['product_key'];

        $checkPurchaseCodeURL = "http://api.emplenio.com/api.php?act=update&purchase_code=" . $productKey . "&version1=" . env('APP_VER') . "&version2=" . config('app.version');
        $result = Curl::getURL($checkPurchaseCodeURL);

        $result = json_decode($result , true);
        $result = is_array( $result ) ? $result : ['status' => 'error' , 'error_msg' => 'Error!!!'];

        if( !($result['status'] == 'ok' && isset($result['sql']) && isset($result['routes'])) )
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error_msg' => isset($result['error_msg']) ? $result['error_msg'] : 'Error!'])->withInput();
        }

        $pdo = $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

        $dbb = base64_decode( $result['sql'] );
        $dbbArray = explode(';' , $dbb);

        foreach( $dbbArray AS $queryOne )
        {
            $queryOne = trim($queryOne);

            if( empty($queryOne) )
                continue;

            $qry = $pdo->prepare( $queryOne );
            $qry->execute();
        }

        file_put_contents(base_path('routes/web.php') , base64_decode( $result['routes'] ));

        session()->flush();

        // update version in .env file
        $envFile = file_get_contents(base_path('.env'));
        $envFile = str_replace('APP_VER=' . env('APP_VER') , 'APP_VER='.config('app.version') , $envFile);
        file_put_contents(base_path('.env') , $envFile);

        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo quitaria esta parte del código en la vista, pero tenés que tener en cuenta que posiblemente el controlador te pida, para pasar al paso4, los datos del codigo de compra. Tendrias que ver la lógica del controlador del paso 4, al pasar del paso 3 al 4, y ver que esta pidiendo ese metodo en particular.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'install/step3/save')) }}

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Purchase key</label>
                            {{ Form::text('product_key', '' , ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Install</button>
```

Y en el método step3Save, tenes que eliminar todo lo relacionado con product_key. No copies y pegues lo que te paso, revisalo, es solo un acercamiento, ya que no puedo probar tu código

```
public function step3Save(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'product_key'   =>  'required|string|min:5|max:255'
    ]);

    $productKey = $validatedData['product_key'];

    $checkPurchaseCodeURL = "http://api.emplenio.com/api.php?purchase_code=" . $productKey . "&version=" . config('app.version');
    $result = Curl::getURL($checkPurchaseCodeURL);

    $result = json_decode($result , true);
    $result = is_array( $result ) ? $result : ['status' => 'error' , 'error_msg' => 'Error!!!'];

    if( !($result['status'] == 'ok' && isset($result['sql']) && isset($result['routes'])) )
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error_msg' => isset($result['error_msg']) ? $result['error_msg'] : 'Error!'])->withInput();
    }
```